# String into multiple string in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace, split

I have not been coding for long and ran into my first issue I just can not seem to figure out.

I have a string `"XX|Y1234$ZT|QW4567"` I need to remove both `$` and `|` and push it into an array like this `['XX', 'Y1234', 'ZT', 'QW4567']`.

I have tried using `.replace` and `.split` in every way I could like of

```
 var array = "XX|Y1234$ZT|QW4567"
 var array2 = [];

 array = array.split("$");

 for(i = o; i <array.length; i++)    
   var loopedArray = array[i].split("|")
   loopedArray.push(array2);        
 }
```

I have tried several other things but would take me awhile to put them all down.

Comment: take care with your code, your `for` loop doesn't have a `{` (opening brace) but have a `}` (closing brace) this will cause issues. also `i = o` didn't you mean `var i = 0` ? Also, `array2` is an empty array that you never modify, there's no logic in pushing it inside `loopedArray`

Answer (score 3):

You can pass Regex into `.split()`. https://regexr.com/ is a great tool for messing with Regex.

```
// Below line returns this array ["XX", "Y1234", "ZT", "QW4567"]
// Splits by $ and |
"XX|Y1234$ZT|QW4567".split(/\$|\|/g);
```

Comment: I guess, `.split(/[\$\|]/g)` scales more nicely, when there're lot of delimiters, however upvoted

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Tipp: You don't even have to escape `|` and `$` inside a character class. And as we're not operating the regex to match blocks by itself, the `g`-match-all-flag isn't needed too. 
`.split(/[|$]/)` should be enough. But i'm with you about your initial statement: This should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet is close, but you've messed up your variables in the `push` statement.

```js
var array = "XX|Y1234$ZT|QW4567"
var array2 = [];

array = array.split("$");

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var loopedArray = array[i].split("|")
  array2.push(loopedArray);
}
array2 = array2.flat();

console.log(array2);
```

However, this can be rewritten much cleaner using `flatMap`. Also note the use of `let` instead of `var` and single quotes `'` instead of double quotes `"`.

```js
let array = 'XX|Y1234$ZT|QW4567'
let array2 = array
  .split('$')
  .flatMap(arrayI => arrayI.split('|'));

console.log(array2);
```

And lastly, `split` already supports multiple delimiters when using regex:

```js
let array = 'XX|Y1234$ZT|QW4567'
let array2 = array.split(/[$|]/);

console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows:

```
"XX|Y1234$ZT|QW4567".replace('$','|').split('|')
```

It will produce the output of:

```
["XX", "Y1234", "ZT", "QW4567"]
```

Comment: worked great. thats a simple great answer thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the split with two parameters `|` and the `$` you will get an strong array which is splittend by the given characters.

```
var array = "XX|Y1234$ZT|QW4567";
var splittedStrings = array.Split('|','$');
foreach(var singelString in splittedStrings){
   Console.WriteLine(singleString);
}
```

**the output is**:

```
XX
Y1234
ZT
QW4567
```